# SQLAlchemy column_property exist in table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's suppose I have three tables.

```
class A(Base):
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  bs = association_proxy("a_b", "b")

class B(Base):
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  extra = Column(String(10), nullable=True)
  as = association_proxy("a_b", "a")

class A_B(Base):
  __table_args__ = (
    UniqueConstraint('a_id', 'b_extra'),
    )
  a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('A.id'), primary_key=True)
  b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('B.id'), primary_key=True)
  b_extra = column_property(
    select([B.extra]).where(B.id=b_id)
    )
  b = relationship("B", backref="a_b")
  a = relationship("A", backref="a_b")
```

And a database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
CREATE TABLE B (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  extra INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
CREATE TABLE A_B (
  a_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  b_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  b_extra INT(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY ('a_id', 'b_extra'),
  KEY a_id,
  KEY b_id,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY ('b_extra') REFERENCES 'B' ('extra'),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY ('b_id') REFERENCES 'B' ('id'),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY ('a_id') REFERENCES 'A' ('id')
)
```

The idea is that A_B is an association table between A and B. The extra data in B is not unique per B, but it *is* unique per A. The problem I am having with this is that when I try to run the script I get `Key Error: b_extra`. I've tried every dirty trick I could think of, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix this.

Edit: To clarify, I want the column_property to exist in the database and participate in updates and inserts like normal.

This is a slightly simplified example from what the real application is, as it's too complex to post here.

Answer (score 0):

the issue here is that your A_B table has a column called "b_extra", but then on your A_B mapping, you're overriding "b_extra" with a column property that attempts to load a different column on a different table, "B.extra".

The intent is not clear here but it seems like you'd get rid of A_B.b_extra since it doesn't seem like you want to write anything to it.  Or if you did want B.extra and A_B.b_extra to exist simultaneously, you'd need to map these two expressions to distinct names.

The A_B.b_extra column property is also a little weird since in between session expiration, it's not going to stay in sync with the relationship route to that attribute, which is just some_a_b.b.extra.

Comment: what I want is for A_B.b_extra to be in sync with B.extra, both in the table and the model. This is so I can have the table level unique constraint so B.extra is unique per A but not per B.

Comment: then you need to map them separately, and use an event to update the A_B.b_extra column whenever A and B are associated together.  The easiest place to do this would be in the `__init__()` method of `A_B`, but if you want more flexibility you can use a [validator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#simple-validators), or [before_flush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.before_flush), others, depends on when you need that value to be updated.

Comment: `before_flush` looks promising, but the documentation is a little confusing. Do you have an example on how to use it?